# Kotlin Aspect With Annotation

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-aop, aspect

**Hello,**
Im working in my own Valid Class i get one problem when i want to get parameters used by my own annotation with  @Around ProceedingJoinPoint return all parameters of the function, i want only the parameter who specified by annotation.
Around fun:

```
 @Around("execution(public * *(..,@com.xyz.event.annotation.Validator (*),..)) ")
fun chek(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any? {
```

Target:

```
    @GetMapping("")
   fun get(@Validator eventDto:EventDto,name:String?):String{
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please improve your problem description and show more of your code, not just method headers. Otherwise: garbage in, garbage out. I.e., you are not going to get any helpful answers.

Comment: WIll the annotated parameter be at arbitrary position on the targeted method or always the starting param?

Comment: i want to get args thats have annotation

Comment: Please read comments more carefully. Neither did you react to mine nor did you answer R.G's question. This way it is very difficult to help you.